# Left Join Doctrine query builder

Tags: php, oop, doctrine-orm

I am trying to understand joins without associations.  Everything I am seeing where people are having success makes sense.  When I apply it to my query, it errors.

```
$query_builder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$query_builder->select('er', 'es')
        ->from('EmployeeRegister', 'er')
        ->leftJoin(
            'EmployeeStatus',
            'es',
            \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::ON,
            'er.eid = es.eid'
        )
        ->where('er.eid = :eid')
        ->setParameter('eid', '0999999');
    $result = $query_builder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This results in an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: SELECT er, es FROM EmployeeRegister er LEFT JOIN EmployeeStatus es ON er.eid = es.eid WHERE er.eid = :eid in /Documents/PHPStormProjects/ax/_vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 /Documents/PHPStormProjects/ax/_vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(491): Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::dqlError('SELECT er, es F...')
#1 /Documents/PHPStormProjects/ax/_vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(991): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->semanticalError('line 0, col 19 ...', Array)
#2 /Documents/PHPStormProjects/ax/_vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1734): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->validateAbstractSchemaName('EmployeeRegiste...')
#3 /Documents/PHPStormProjects/ax/_vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1584): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->RangeVariableDeclaration()
#4 /Us in /Documents/PHPStormProjects/ax/_vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php on line 65
```

Any suggestions would be super helpful.  Still learning doctrine in general.

Comment: You don't have to specify the ON portion if your relationship is mapped in the ORM. Can we have a look at the relevant models?

Comment: The relationship is not mapped.

When you say models, I am not using Symfony or anything.  Do you want to see the entities? There isn't anything crazy there, just the getters and setters and the properties of the class

Comment: Update:  I wasnt requiring the EmployeeStatus entities.  now when i do, I get the Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->syntaxError('end of string') error which makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

If someone could explain what or why this is in Doctrine 2.  When I changed the join to use WITH instead of ON it works.

```
$query_builder->select('er', 'es')
    ->from('EmployeeRegister', 'er')
    ->leftJoin(
        'EmployeeStatus',
        'es',
        \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
        'er.eid = es.eid'
    )
    ->where('er.eid = :eid')
    ->setParameter('eid', '0999999');
```

In what scenarios does ON work?  I tried some random ones and nothing seems to work with ON, only WITH.